# Properly Attach to existing chrome driver with C# Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have used this [method](https://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium-csharp/) designed by Tarun Lalwani to attach a Selenium Chrome driver by reusing the url and the sessionID in C#. This attach is partly working but some driver methods such as FindElement(By.ID) display error **"invalid argument: invalid locator (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.114)"**  on this line:

```
    var respBase = base.Execute(driverCommandToExecute, parameters);
```

My guess is that it is due to options or desired capabilities are empty when the driver is attached.But I havent find a way to properly set it on ReuseRemoteWebDriver.
I include an image of the look of the attached driver
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQN99.png).
How can I solve this issue so I can attach the previous chrome driver and keep all expected selenium functionalities?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            InputSimulator teclado = new InputSimulator();
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.UseSpecCompliantProtocol = true;
            ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"Thepathofchromedriver");
            IWebDriver driver;
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

            Uri myUri = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:65431", UriKind.Absolute);
            service.Port = 65431;
            string ID = "1f42d5f0ad105910e8d2fc7be23480a9";
            if (ID != "")
            {
                
                IWebDriver drivertest1 = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
                
                IWebDriver drivertest = new ReuseRemoteWebDriver(myUri, ID,capabilities,options);
                driver = drivertest;
            }
            else
            {
                IWebDriver drivertest = new ChromeDriver(service,options);
                
                driver = drivertest;


            }

        IWebElement inputUser = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ID"));}


public class ReuseRemoteWebDriver : OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver
    {
        private String _sessionId;
        
        public ReuseRemoteWebDriver(Uri remoteAddress, String sessionId, OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DesiredCapabilities capability, ChromeOptions options)
            : base(remoteAddress,options)

        {
            this._sessionId = sessionId;
            var sessionIdBase = this.GetType()
                .BaseType
                .GetField("sessionId",
                          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            sessionIdBase.SetValue(this, new OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.SessionId(sessionId));

            
        }

        protected override OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.Response
            Execute(string driverCommandToExecute, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
        {
            if (driverCommandToExecute == OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverCommand.NewSession)
            {
                var resp = new OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.Response();
                resp.Status = OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverResult.Success;
                resp.SessionId = this._sessionId;
                resp.Value = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, Object>();
                return resp;
            }
            var respBase = base.Execute(driverCommandToExecute, parameters);
            return respBase;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: I could fix most issues, as I indicated in the reply.
the most important functionality I couldn't manage to recover was the inject js scripts with

```
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    var script = "your script";
    js.ExecuteScript(script);
```

Any idea regarding how to recover the inject script functionality would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, I modified the previous class as following, so I can use the sendKeysToElement

```
    public class ReuseRemoteWebDriver : OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver
    {
        private String _sessionId;

        public ReuseRemoteWebDriver(Uri remoteAddress, String sessionId, ChromeOptions options, ChromeDriverService service)
            : base(remoteAddress, options)

        {
            //object x = driver;
            this._sessionId = sessionId;

            var sessionIdBase = this.GetType()
                .BaseType
                .GetField("sessionId",
                          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);


            //System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> x = this.GetCapabilitiesDictionary(capability);


            sessionIdBase.SetValue(this, new OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.SessionId(sessionId));


        }

        protected override OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.Response
            Execute(string driverCommandToExecute, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
        {
            if (driverCommandToExecute == OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverCommand.NewSession)
            {
                var resp = new OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.Response();
                resp.Status = OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverResult.Success;
                resp.SessionId = this._sessionId;
                resp.Value = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, Object>();
                return resp;
            }
            if (driverCommandToExecute == "sendKeysToElement")
            {
                object[] array = (object[])parameters["value"];

                string stringfinal = (string)array[0].ToString();


                parameters.Add("text", stringfinal);

            }
            if (driverCommandToExecute == "executeScript")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            var respBase = base.Execute(driverCommandToExecute, parameters);
            return respBase;
        }
    }
}
```

In other class I used the following method to properly used Selenium waits.

```
   public Boolean WaitInteligente(WebDriverWait wait, string condition, By selector = null, 
            IWebElement optionalWebElement = null,string optionalstring = null,
            bool optionalbool = false,bool devolverexcepcion=true )
        {
            TimeSpan Tiempo = wait.Timeout;
            var globalclock = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Boolean stop = false;
            double segundos = globalclock.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
            Exception exception = null;
            //globalclock.Stop();
            while (segundos <= Tiempo.TotalSeconds)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                try
                {
                    segundos = globalclock.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                    if (condition == "ElementExists")
                        wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(selector));
                    if (condition == "ElementIsVisible")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(selector));
                    if (condition == "ElementToBeClickable")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(selector));
                    if (condition == "ElementToBeSelected")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeSelected(selector));
                    if (condition == "FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(selector));
                    if (condition == "InvisibilityOfElementLocated")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(selector));
                    if (condition == "PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(selector));
                    if (condition == "VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(selector));
                    if (condition == "AlertIsPresent")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
                    if (condition == "ElementToBeSelected")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeSelected(optionalWebElement));
                    if (condition == "InvisibilityOfElementWithText")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementWithText(selector,optionalstring));
                    if (condition == "StalenessOf")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(optionalWebElement));
                    if (condition == "TextToBePresentInElement")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(optionalWebElement,optionalstring));
                    if (condition == "TextToBePresentInElementLocated")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(selector, optionalstring));
                    if (condition == "TextToBePresentInElementValue")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementValue(selector, optionalstring));
                    if (condition == "TitleContains")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TitleContains(optionalstring));
                    if (condition == "TitleIs")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TitleIs(optionalstring));
                    if (condition == "UrlContains")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlContains(optionalstring));
                    if (condition == "UrlMatches")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlMatches(optionalstring));
                    if (condition == "UrlToBe")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlToBe(optionalstring));
                    if (condition == "FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(optionalstring));
                    if (condition == "AlertState")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertState(optionalbool));
                    if (condition == "ElementSelectionStateToBe")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementSelectionStateToBe(selector,optionalbool));
                    if (condition == "ElementSelectionStateToBe")
                        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementSelectionStateToBe(selector, optionalbool));


                    stop = true;
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                     e = new Exception(selector.ToString() + condition + e.Message);
                    exception = e;
                }
            }

            if (!stop && devolverexcepcion)
                throw exception;

            return stop;
        }
```

The methods that are not working properly when attached are
driver.FindElement(By.Id) and driver.FindElement(By.ClassName) which can be easily circumvented by using a By.CssSelector call to the ID  or Classname respectively.

The most important functionality I couldn't recover was the inject js scripts with

```
  IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var script = "your script";
js.ExecuteScript(script);
```

Any idea regarding how to recover the inject script functionality would be appreciated.